# USB flashdrive can't be formated, detected but no disc

Tags: usb

USB flashdrive can't be formated, detected but no disc

[please see the video for my problem](https://youtu.be/S7QVlBgYh_4)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to format it with diskpart.
Open the command prompt as an admin, then enter "diskpart". 
Now enter "list vol". 
If the USB Drive appears there, enter "select vol *NUMBER OF THE VOLUME*". 
After that enter list vol again. 
The USB drive should now be selecte with a little * in front of it. 
Than you can enter "format fs=fat32 quick" to format it with fat32.
After it is formatted all the data on it is gone.